# Python SciPy - obtain minimum AIC for SARIMAX

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

I am trying to obtain p and q parameters for which the AIC quotient of a seasonal Arima function is minimum, using Scipy brute. p & q are taking values in range 0-2 and for simplicity, I fixed d and D below.

The code is:

```
def objfunc(grid):
    p, q = grid
    mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(timeseries,order=(p,0,q),
        seasonal_order=(p,1,q,12),
        enforce_stationarity=False,
        enforce_invertibility=False)
    results = mod.fit()
    return results.aic;

grid = (slice(1, 3, 1),slice(1, 3, 1))
Solution = brute(objfunc, grid, finish=None,full_output = True)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len(). Probably SARIMAX function generates errors for some p&q values but I am not sure how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: It might help if you post the entire traceback error message.

Comment: The grid is quite small. Can you manually find values for `p` and `q` which raise the `TypeError`? That could help focus our attention on the root-cause of the problem.

Comment: What is `timeseries`? Posting a short, runnable example which reproduces the error would be marvelous.